# Create an order relationship based on node attributes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm new to Neo4j and I have a few nodes created with an attribute called 'order'. I'd like to create a relationship between each pair of node respecting the order implied by the 'order' attribute, but I have no idea how.

Example :

```
(:node { order: 2 }), (:node { order: 4 }), (:node { order: 1 })
```

would give :

```
(:node { order: 1 })->(:node { order: 2 })->(:node {order: 4)
```

// This is not Neo4j syntax, this is just to make my question clear.

By advance, a big thank you :)

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query should create a chain of `node` nodes in `order` order (using `NEXT` relationships):

```
MATCH (n:node)
WITH n
ORDER BY n.order
WITH COLLECT(n) AS ns
UNWIND RANGE(0, SIZE(ns)-2) AS i
WITH ns[i] AS a, ns[i+1] AS b
CREATE (a)-[:NEXT]->(b)
```